# Reference a sibling's value in a .value() call?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, sqlxml

I'm trying to get the value of an element out of an xml doc based on the value of a sibling element.

For example, `<data>` has a series of `<questions>`, each `<questions>` has a series of `<answers>` and an `<answer>` that constains the index of the answer the person has chosen.

What I'm trying to ask is if there's any `<questions>` in my set that has an `<answer>` that points to one of the `<answers>` entries that has an `<isCorrect>` value of "true".  Right now I just care if one of the questions has a correct answer.

```
<data>
  <questions>
    <isGraded>true</isGraded>
    <answers>
      <title>first answer</title>
      <isCorrect>true</isCorrect>
    </answers>
    <answers>
      <title>second answer</title>
      <isCorrect>false</isCorrect>
    </answers>
    <answer>1</answer>
  </questions>
  <questions>
    <isGraded>true</isGraded>
    <answers>
      <title>first answer</title>
      <isCorrect>false</isCorrect>
    </answers>
    <answers>
      <title>second answer</title>
      <isCorrect>true</isCorrect>
    </answers>
    <answer>0</answer>
  </questions>
</data>
```

This is what I'm down to:

`SET @myValue = @myDoc.value('(/data//questions[isGraded[1]="true"]/child::answers[position() = parent::answer+1][isCorrect="true"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')`

If I replace the "parent::answer+1" part with the value from the `<answer>` I get the value I'm looking for, but I don't know how to automatically look at the `<answer>` elements value to do this.

Or is this even possible?

Comment: How does `<isGraded>` affect the outcome? And what exactly is the expected outcome?

Comment: @JackFleeting it's just indicates whether that's a question that is to be graded or not.  In my case, I don't care about that ones that have isGraded as false.  Expected outcome, anything that indicates that this document has a question that was answered correctly.  true vs false, something vs null, doesn't matter to me

Comment: That's better, but still unclear, and I think it's in part because your tag names are confusing. Each `<questions>` has one child named `<isGraded>`, two children named `<answers>` and one child named `<answer>` and the relationship between them isn't clear. Maybe changing the tag names will help, as well as adding a couple of examples where some elements have different values (e.g., `<isGraded>false</isGraded>`).

Comment: Does this work for you? `select @myDoc.exist('/data/questions[answers[position() - 1 = ../answer]/isCorrect = "true"]')`